# How to debug a webpacker CSS loading issue in a react component?

Tags: css, reactjs, fullcalendar, ruby-on-rails-5.2, webpacker

I've got a rails app with increasing amounts of react on the front-end (using the `react-rails` and `webpacker` gems). I'm in the process of moving away from `JQuery-mobile` look and feel.

I am trying to add `fullcalendar` using their (beta) [react](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react) component (following their instructions) but I cannot seem to get any of the css to load/apply. I get the data displaying with the buttons, but no fullcalendar formatting/images. This is my code:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list'
import momentPlugin from '@fullcalendar/moment'

import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css'
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/list/main.css';


class CourseCalendar extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const header = {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth, dayGridWeek, listMonth'
    }

    return (
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, listPlugin ]}
        header={header}
        themeSystem='standard'
        events={[
          { title: 'event 1', allDay: true,
            start: '2019-04-22', end: '2019-4-22' },
          { title: 'event 2', allDay: true,
            start: '2019-04-25', end: '2019-4-30' }
        ]}

      />
    );
  }
}
```

I have not used `import` to bring in stylesheets before and I can't seem to figure out how to debug it.

- How can I verify that these `main.css` files loaded?
- How can I figure out if there are files that it wasn't able to load?
- Do I need to explicitly install or configure a css-loader?
- What am I missing?

** Update **

I've made this work by adding `@import` statements to the page's scss file, but this seems a sub-par solution. Does anyone know how I can make the `import` in the react component function properly? Otherwise, can anyone explain why it does/should not?

Answer (score 2):

You are making mistake with the path of css, please type it correctly.

try this,

```
import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
```

`~` is missing in your path so, webpack is not able find the css file.

here, `~` means path to `node_modules` so, you can simply go to that path and see if file exist or not.

see, the documentation [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react)

Comment: I did see that in the docs, but it doesn't seem to work. Unfortunately, when I add that in, it errors out and fails to build indicating that it could not find the document. It seems webpacker on rails does not like the `~` (https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/css.md). Any other ideas?